# Search multiple cells

Tags: excel-formula

I want to find the value `"1"` in the range `B1:B31` and output the value `A1`

Kind of like this:

```
If B1:B31 is 1, Then A1, Else 0
```

This does not work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",B1:B31)),A1,"")
```

What is the proper formula?

Comment: is `1` the only value in the cell or is it part of a string.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,B1:B31,0)),A1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, now I need to have the output (currently shown in the equation as A1), to correspond to the B cell, so in the above, it would return the value from A8.

Comment: Sounds like you where looking for a index - match solution, rather then looking for it being a number. `INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1;B:B,0))`